# Is there another way to explicitly initialise parent class?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

I'm looking for a way to initiate my parent class after some changes are done in child class.

Ex:

```
class Parent {
public:
    Parent(stream f) {
    //some code
    }
};

class Child : public Parent {
public:
    Child(string fileName) : Parent(???) {    // Line 10
    //some code
    }
};
```

In Line 10 I should give fstream created using "fileName".
Where can I create this stream variable?

Comment: You can create it exactly where `???` are. `Parent(std::fstream(filename))`

Comment: `Where can I create this stream variable?` What is your problem creating it at the `???`?

Comment: But when it comes to more complicated work, I couldn't do this in just one function/line.

Comment: `But when it comes to more complicated work, I couldn't do this in just one function/line.` why do you think that this is the case? You need to show an example that illustrates for which situation you think it will not work.

Comment: @MaYar Then make static member function and do the work in there. Then return the value you want to pass to the parent. Call the function in the initializer list.

Comment: or direct called lambda.

Comment: There is only one case in which you cannot make it work: if you would need member variables of `Child` to create `Parent`. All others are basically solved with passing some variable directly or delegating work to function that will do more complex work.

Comment: Just because a pair of classes are named `Parent` and `Child` doesn't make them so. None of the shown classes inherit from the other, as such they have no relationship whatsoever. Your question is unclear.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thanks for your attention, it was my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The comments already show a possible way, so you could do it like this:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

class Parent {
public:
    Parent(std::fstream f) {
        // some code
    }
};

class Child : public Parent {
public:
    // Do it like this:
    Child(std::string fileName) : Parent(std::fstream(fileName)) {
        // some code
    }
};
```

One more thing: `Parent` obviously needs to be a direct base class of `Child`, so I modified the code accordingly. Otherwise it would not compile.

Comment: This is unlikely to work, since `std::fstream` is not copyable.

Comment: Well, it works just fine with GCC 9 on my machine. I can even read some content from the file stream in `Parent`'s constructor like this: `Parent(std::fstream f) { std::string s; std::getline(f, s); std::cout << s << std::endl; }` Looks like there is no need to copy.